# Construct following semidecidable sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computability, recursive-algorithms

Being an undergrad, was looking through our previous year task books during exam preparation and got stuck on this one:

Are there such semidecidable (recursively enumerable) sets X, Y that their composition $X \cdot Y=\{xy| \forall x\in X, \forall y\in Y \}$ is recursive?

Do you have any ideas?